# Check if Twitter account was previously followed

Tags: api, twitter

Many Twitter helper apps, like [CrowdFireApp](https://crowdfireapp.com), have the ability to check if you have followed an account before. This is good for when you want to follow an account but can't remember if you have followed it before.

Is this possible using the twitter API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't use the Twitter API to check if you have followed an account before. [See this response from Andy Piper](https://twitter.com/andypiper/status/643868977081503745), developer advocate at Twitter.